# Compute coefficient of generating function

Tags: approximation

Given a generating function $F(z)$, is there any way to compute the coefficient $a_k$ of $z^k$ by Mathematica? One method is to calculate by the equation  $\frac{F^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$. However, this approach is not feasible for $k$ large.

Comment: Look into `SeriesCoefficient`.

Comment: @RiemannZeta do you have any idea of how they implemented it? I mean any bound for the deviation/approximation?

Comment: Section 7.3 of Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik (May 1989 edition) describes in detail what I suspect is buried in `SeriesCoefficient`.

Answer (score 3):

Via Cauchy integral formula:

```
Block[{f = #/(1 - # + #^2)^2 &, k = 100},
 1/(2 Pi I)
   Integrate[f[x]/x^(k + 1), Flatten@{x, {1, I, -1, -I, 1}/16}, 
   Assumptions -> k >= 0 && k \[Element] Integers]
 ]
(*  -34  *)
```

Complex path `Flatten@{x, {1, I, -1, -I, 1}/16}` may require adjustment for other functions.

Check via derivatives:

```
D[x/(1 - x + x^2)^2, {x, 100}]/100! /. x -> 0
(*  -34  *)
```

Via `SeriesCoefficient`:

```
SeriesCoefficient[x/(1 - x + x^2)^2, {x, 0, 100}]
(*  -34  *)
```

For a general answer, when one may be computed, I would first try
`SeriesCoefficient`:

```
SeriesCoefficient[x/(1 - x + x^2)^2, {x, 0, k}]
```

For numerical approximation, I would use `NIntegrate[]`, possibly with a high `WorkingPrecision`, in the Cauchy integral formula:

```
Block[{f = #/(1 - # + #^2)^2 &, k = 100, r = 1/2, x0 = 0},
   1/(2 Pi I)
     NIntegrate[
     f[x]/x^(k + 1) Dt[x, t] /. x -> x0 + r*Exp[I t], {t, -Pi, Pi},
     Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 16,
      WorkingPrecision -> 50]
   ] // N // Rationalize
(*  -34  *)
```

Since no test functions were given in the OP, it's hard to know what to recommend for the OP's case.

Answer (score 1):

Formula for the nth term:

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/(1-x)^2,{x,0,n}]
```

It seems more efficient to compute a formula for the nth term, then use `Simplify` and apply (`/. n -> 100)`, rather than using `SeriesCoefficient` to calculate the coefficient for the 100th term directly.

Series expansion up to 10th order:

```
Series[1/((1-x^3)^2(1-x^2)^3),{x,0,10}]
```

Comment: +1 But `D[1/(1 - x)^2, {x, k}]/k! /. x -> 0` is competitive in timing even for $k=100$.

Comment: I'm not sure if SeriesCoefficient does any special tricks. For example, 1/(1-x)^2 has trivial terms, but  1/((1-x^3)^2(1-x^2)^3) could be computed as a product of two GFs with simple combinatorial interpretations, while taking derivatives would be ugly.